# Generate 3D rendering / DEM from NOAA ENC files?

Tags: qgis, dem, qgis2threejs, noaa

Is there a way to generate a 3D rendering of the underwater topography lines from NOAA ENC files in QGIS?

I want to take the depth contours and generate a 3D or shaded relief map from this.

I successfully took a DEM file from NOAA and used qgis2threejs to generate the following image (below). The challenge is, DEM coverage is limited. It would be cool to generate a shaded relief based on the contour lines. That way, any lake or any ENC chart I could generate something. I understand that some interpolation would be needed from the tool/function...I'm ok with that.

I was hoping that ENC files have enough meta data that could be used for the contour line depth to at least seed the building of the relief map; but maybe my expectations are not reasonable.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not without extensive GIS work.  The NOAA ENC files are raster data.  While these ENC files include depth soundings (and apparently, contours)  these data are just pixels in the image.  You could bring the ENC into QGIS, create a new point or line file, and digitize and attribute your points or lines based off of the stuff shown on the ENC.  Then, you would need to [interpolate these vector data](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/spatial_analysis_interpolation.html) into a raster surface using available interpolation tools in QGIS.  Some knowledge of vertical datum conversion and coordinate reference systems would be required on your part to ensure your resulting data was useful for your end purpose (the X, Y, Z values matched).  Get started and report back when you have a single problem that you need solving.